# Confliction when renewing the images which use a certain port (with using networkmode HOST)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I am using ECS on EC2 with `networkmode.HOST` .

Container image is in ECR and in image there is a server which waiting on port `8011`

When I want to update the container with new image from ECR.

I do like this

```
 aws ecs update-service --force-new-deployment --service my-service --cluster my-ec2-cluster
```

This commands try to relaunch new container and when new container is launched ,shutdown the old container.

However with `networkmode.HOST`, old container prevent new container's launch (because , it occupy the port already)

So, I need to stop the old task maually, and wait the new task launched.

So there appears a few seconds or minutes blank for task.

Is there any solution for this?

There is no way to avoid this with networkmode.HOST?

Is my command correct for the purpose to re-new the image?

Comment: You in fact can't do a zero-downtime update using host networking.  You also shouldn't need it for most applications, and it might not make sense in a multi-host environment like ECS.  Can you remove that option?